# Inserting a link to another post in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I'm putting together a site based on a Wordpress template, and was wondering if there's a way to link one post to another without entering the full URL. I'd like to be able to use something that doesn't change if the parent directory or subdomain changes. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Posts**

To link to a Post, find the ID of the target post on the Posts administration panel, and insert it in place of the '123' in this link:

```
<a href="index.php?p=123">Post Title</a>
```

**Categories**

To link to a Category, find the ID of the target Category on the Categories administration panel, and insert it in place of the '7' in this link:

```
<a href="index.php?cat=7">Category Title</a>
```

**Pages**

To link to a Page, find the ID of the target Page on the Pages administration panel, and insert it in place of the '42' in this link:

```
<a href="index.php?page_id=42">Page title</a>
```

(From [Wordpress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Linking_Posts_Pages_and_Categories#Pages))

Answer (score 1):

[Linking Posts, Pages, and Categories](http://codex.wordpress.org/Linking_Posts_Pages_and_Categories)

Something like: <a href="index.php?p=123">Post Title</a> should work even if you use permalinks.

Answer (score 0):

use below code to get particular post url and Title only by post id.

replace $postid with your post id that you want to display.

```
$postid = 1;  
echo '<a href="'.get_permalink($postid).'">'.get_the_title($postid).'</a>';
```